# Database design for Gym fee Submission

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

I need suggestions on a database design.

I am currently working on designing a DBMS for a GYM. 
After designing courses Classes Instructors Products Now I Want to Submit fee with year and month
I think I have to create 3 tables of Year Month fee

```
tbl_year.year_id, tbl_year.year_name
tbl_month.mon_id,tbl_month.mon_name
tbl_fee.fee_id,tbl_fee.fee_cus_id, tbl_fee.fee_year_id, tbl_fee.fee_mon_id, tbl_fee.fee_status
```

guide me how I do?

Comment: what is the need for separate year and month tables?

Comment: can't you just store the end of submission date?

Comment: Do _not_ normalize dates.  Use `DATE` or `DATETIME`, then format with `DATE_FORMAT()`.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a table called memberships with Id, Membership_name, price, duration(if this membership is 1 month or 1year) and then just assign the memberships to your person.